CustomInput in react final form with complex value
I am trying to create a customInput which would encapsulate an object value:
export type InputWithOptOutValue = {
  hasOptIn: boolean;
  optInValue: string;
};

All the examples I have seen till now assumes that the input fields have primitive types like: string | number | readonly string[] | undefined. Is this an inherent limitation in react final form?
